# Declared CheckBox Showing up as Undeclared in Validator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm getting an error saying that `CheckBox1` is not declared, but it definitely is, earlier in the `gridview`. The background is that users are approving records in a `gridview`. If the record is not approved, the checkbox is unchecked. Because it was not approved, I would also like to require a comment from the user explaining why. *The comment is only required if the checkbox is unchecked.*

I've tried shifting the validators around, but I'm not having any luck. Is there something I'm missing? Still pretty new to `asp.net`. Back end is `vb.net`. Below is the comment field. If more is required, just let me know.

The Error:

> 'CheckBox1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

The Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Comment" MaxLength="200" runat="server" Width="500px" Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
            Display = "Dynamic" 
            ControlToValidate = "Comment" 
            ID="RegularExpressionValidator" 
            ValidationExpression = "^[a-zA-Z0-9'@&#.\s]{2,200}$"
            runat="server"  
            ForeColor="red" 
            ErrorMessage="!">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <%If CheckBox1.Checked = "False" then%>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="Comment"
                ErrorMessage="*Required"
                ForeColor="Red">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <%Else%>
        <%End If%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You cannot access other Controls inside a GridView template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot ***easily*** disable and enable ***RequiredFieldValidator*** based on logic at ***client-side*** not to mention those controls are in GridView.

My suggestion will be not to use RequiredFieldValidator for that particular scenario. Then let the user posts the form, and you validate those inputs at server-side.

Comment: What I was thinking of doing was setting up a CustomValidator within the ItemTemplate to call a sub on the vb.net-side that would the GridView, line by line to check the status of the checkbox and comment textbox. Does that seem like a workable solution?

Comment: Most CustomValidator validate at server-side, unless you create the one which can validate both client-side and server-side; it is not an easy task. If you want, you can try.